# windows 8.1 update disabled local website for IE

Tags: windows, hosts-file, internet-explorer-11

I use the Windows hosts file to resolve domains for websites on my local IIS. It worked great under Windows 8. I just updated to Windows 8.1 and none of my local sites will resolve in IE11. Even 127.0.0.1 will not resolve to the Default Website in IE. How can I get this working again?

EDIT:

I opened Fiddler2 and used the new Win8 Config button to add IE to Loopback Exemption. Now I can get to locally hosted sites again.

Does IE11 have some kind of loopback protection that would prevent viewing locally hosted sites?

Comment: The hosts file likely was replaced have you checked that?  Because the behavior has not been changed

Comment: The host file was carried over. I did just notice there are a couple Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapters now. Were those in the base Windows 8 install? Perhaps that is affecting the DNS lookups.

Comment: If you had Hyper-V installed previously then they would be installed

Comment: Okay, after remaking the hosts file and flushing DNS, I can now get local sites to resolve in Chrome and Firefox (Chrome used to never open local addresses), but just IE11 won't resolve any local address. It won't even resolve 127.0.0.1 with the default website turned on. Perhaps I should change the name of this post to include IE11

Comment: Okay, weird. I opened Fiddler2 and used the new Win8 Config button to add IE to Loopback Exemption. Now I can get to locally hosted sites again. Something is definitely different in Win 8.1 that affects self-hosting. Can anyone shed light on this?